# TFS Merge by File Version

Tags: version-control, tfs, visual-sourcesafe

I posted a question a while back concerning the downsides to Merging individual files.

[Is it okay to merge individual files from one branch to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8175892/is-it-okay-to-merge-individual-files-from-one-branch-to-another)

The answer posted said that I should do by changeset rather than by file version. However, I've been reading that merging by changeset (cherry picking) is a very bad idea. You might end up getting merges you don't intend unless you really understand the contents of each changeset  and how TFS stores deltas.

I'm trying to convince my team in our migration from VSS to TFS that we should only be merging at the branch level. However, I lack a good example of the potential impacts of merging by file version. Can anyone explain or provide a good link to information on merging by file version (not necessarily changeset).

Something I'm not sure on is if you merge by file version, are you still merging the changesets associated with that file version? If those changesets affect other files, do those files get changed?

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TFS doesn't have a concept of file versions. If you want to merge a specific version of a specific file you have to use a combination of filename and changeset something like

`tf merge $/TP/Branch1/file1.cs $/TP/Branch2/file1.cs /version:C1234`

you can do the same using the GUI by selecting the file, Right click, and merge. In the merge wizard choose "selected changesets" from the dropdown instead of "latest version"  (you can do the same thing at the folder level.)

If you merge this way the TFS remembers that the changeset has been partially merged and will prompt you to merge the rest of the changeset next time you merge.

you can see partial merges by using

`tf merge $/TP/Branch1 $/TP/Branch2 /recursive /candidate` any changesets in the list with a * next to them have been partially merged already

Comment: Ahh, "partially merged" changesets. That's what I was wondering about. I was wondering how it handled splitting up changesets... or if it was even possible. So if I merge via "latest version" in the GUI will I be permanently condemning myself to the "prompt to merge the rest of the changeset"? Are there other downsides to these partial merges?

Comment: You will be prompted if you merge at a higher level, e.g. You have a changeset that contains files in 2 seperate folders. You merge the changes from 1 of the folders, if you merge the same folder again you wont be prompted. If you merge at the root, or the other folder you'll be prompted.